# richtextbox application test c#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm very new to c#. I created a forms. A richtextbox and a button in it.

I have a list of operators: Sum, Subtract,Multi,Div.I want to run a small richtextbox test. For example,in the richtextbox I write a text (eg. Sum(1,2)) and then click the button. A return result(eg.3) prints in the richtextbox.

My idea is to use string contains

```
foreach( var element in operatorlist)
{
  string text=richtextbox.text;
  if( text.contains(element)== true)
  {
     element(parameter1,parameter2);//something like this
  }
}
```

I met two questions right row.

My first question is how to get the mathematical operation from the richtextbox text. Is there a better way than mine?

My second question is once we know the operator,how to allocate the two parameters in the richtextbox to the operator.

I'm not asking for coding, I'm just looking for ideas. If you have a good idea and wish to share.

Comment: You can parse the last line. Everyone from index 0 to `(` is the keyword. Everything between `(` and `)` are your parameters, split on `,`

Comment: My personal preference for this would be to give them a locked RichTextBox and a standard text box. They enter the command in the text box, you then post it to the RichText, parse, process and display results.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Wieder. I try to repeat your idea could u tell me it's correct or not. You mean I can parese the sum(1,2) and split it to two part. First: sum, second parameters 1,2 and then use operator in my list ,at last print the result to the richtextbox. Is that your idea?

Comment: @ Jeffrey Wieder In this case,could you tell me how to use split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think this comes down to personal style. Your way will definitely work, so good on you for that. The way I would do it is to create a Dictionary of strings to an enum. So for example, said dictionary and enum might look like this:

`enum Operator { Addition = 0, Subtraction = 1, Multiplication = 2, Division = 3, etc};`

```
    var operatorDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Operator>() 
    {
        {"Addition", Operator.Addition},
        {"Subtraction", Operator.Subtraction},
        etc...
    };
```

Then to get the value you would just do

```
Operator operation;
operatorDictionary.TryGetValue(string operationString, out operation);
```

and you would have to then build some code that switches through the Operators and performs the correct operation. There is even a way of converting a string to an enum, so that would work as well.

2. It looks like the parameters are in a consistent format, so you would just make a simple method that splits by parenthesis and the comma, and returns the strings that it found.

Let me know if you need anything explained more.

Comment: @ Nicholas Ellingson thx for your help. Could you explain a little more about spliting by parenthesis and the comma?because i'm not familiar with split ,

Comment: check out the following spots: [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) and [String.Split Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

They will give you some help on splitting strings.
So for example, to get the first parameter (the operation), I would do: `string[] splitString = toParse.Split(new char[]{ '(' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` and then the operation parameter would be `splitString[0]`. Then, to get the first number parameter, I would split `splitString[1]` by the comma character.

Comment: You could also use regex, but that would be pretty confusing to someone who's new to programming. However, you will likely eventually have to use regex at some point if you are ever coding professionally, so it might be worth doing some research on.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate an expression using the **DataTable.Compute** function:

```
int p1 = 1 ; string s1 = p1.ToString() ;
int p2 = 2 ; string s2 = p2.ToString() ;
int p3 = 3 ; string s3 = p3.ToString() ;
// Compute (p1+p2)*p3 ==> 9
int result = new DataTable().Compute( "("+s1+"+"+s2+")*"+s3+")","") ;
```

or directly:

```
string expression = "(1+2)*3" ;
int result = new DataTable().Compute(expression,"") ;
```